# Programmatically find the number of CPUs on a machine (CPUS, not cores)

Tags: multithreading, multicore

Is there any way to find programmatically (C code only, linux OS)  number of physical CPUs (not cores) ? (something similar to sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF))

All solutions found on this site explain how to find number of cores.
I need this information to set threads which exchange data frequently to run on the same physical CPU.
I can get this information from /proc/cpuinfo but I prefer to chose this as second option.